# (Apps Script - Slack incoming Webhook) Not sending a message when a value is undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to utilize slack incoming webhooks to let my teammates know when values in a shared google spreadsheet are updated.

Now, the logic is just like following:

1. 5th Column is for english name of a new hire.
2. When Column 5 is filled, it sends out a message via slack.

I'd like to add a condition not to send out a message when Column 5 value (Engish name) is not filled (undefined), since the trigger starts even when I delete the text value of Column 5.

How can i solve this problem?

```js
function eng_name(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 5 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() === "sheetname")
  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var name_eng = e.value;
  

  var url = "incoming webhhooks url";
  var payload = {
    text: "blahblah" + name_eng
}
```

I tried to put e.range.getValue !== undefined OR e.range.getValue !== null as a condition, but couldn't get the result what i want.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function eng_name(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.columnStart == 5 && sheet.getSheetName() === "sheetname" && !range.isBlank()) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var name_eng = e.value;
    var url = "incoming webhhooks url";
    var payload = {
      text: "blahblah" + name_eng
    }
```

- In this modification, in order to check whether the edited cell is blank, `isBlank()` is used.
- And, the event object is used.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)